# Android : Error in R.java class

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having a strange error that I can not resolve in class R.java in my android application

the error is in the following line

```
 public static final class string {

            public static final int =0x7f05002f;
```

because it has no variable after the `int`

can anyone help me please with this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your **strings.xml** file.It seems like you have saved some value without assigning any name to that.

**Look for an entry not having any `name` attribute.** something like `<string>8</string>`, either remove that or assign a name attribute to that like `<string name="anyname">8</string>`

Comment: In my case, I am having the same problem in "drawable" section. public static final int 10423915_788252547888386_7550641554682340139_n=0x7f020000; Any idea ?

Answer (score 6):

`R.java` is auto-generated, and is not meant to be edited manually.

If you face issues, delete `R.java` and rebuild your project and it will be generated again, according to your layout.

If problem persists, look into your xml files ( `strings.xml, layout.xml, etc`) for any errors.

Comment: I deleted it many times and it is generated again with the same error ... this is really weird and I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Then the error is in one of your XML files. Check layout.xml and strings.xml.

Comment: the problem was in strings.xml i had a string that has no name thank you

Answer (score 0):

A bad R.java would mean an error somewhere else. If deleting it and rebuilding the projetc doesn't solve it look at your manifest and other xml resources for errors.

Comment: the problem was in strings.xml

i had a string that has no name

thank you